# Hide scripts from FCK Editor

Tags: fckeditor

Is there any way to hide text and scripts from appearing in FCK editor in normal view ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "hiding text and scripts", but I do know that you can customize the [toolbar](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar). The project is very well documented. You should be able to find anything you need to know at the [doc site](http://docs.fckeditor.net/).

Comment: I want editors to see comments and hints when they are editing a page , i don't what the hints appearing in the published view of the page

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, the HTML you see Source view will be displayed in the normal view exactly the same way it will be displayed in the browser later. However, the CSS applied in this two cases is different.

That gives you an opportunity, for example, to hide a spoiler in final page, but show it in normal view in the editor window. You can use CSS to do it the other way around, but I do not see why you may want it.